# Convert a cell into different columns & rows of the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to scrape a table out of a site. I have tried to convert data_row to a Pandas DataFrame; however, all the data are lumped in one cell of the DataFrame. Would you guys please help me convert the data_row into a Pandas DataFrame with "Business Mileage, "Charitable Mileage," "Medical mileage," and "Moving mileage" as rows and "2016," "2015," "2014," "2013," "2012," "2011," and "2010" as columns ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import pandas as pd
r = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.smbiz.com/sbrl003.html#cmv')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
print soup.prettify()
data_row = soup.findAll('pre')[0:1]
```

Comment: have you tried using `pd.read_html()`? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html

Comment: I am using iPython Notebook 2. I have tried using pd.read_html(); however, I received an error message, which is "No module named html5lib."

Comment: Try running `pip install html5lib` first.

Comment: I have tried to run pip install html5lib; but received an error message as "invalid syntax"

Comment: You did not run `pip install html5lib` from within iPython, did you? Please run it from the terminal (not python)